# Unable to install apt-transport-https on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I want to install docker on raspberry, i used the script on docker:https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script
I run the script, then i met this issue:

```
    sudo sh get-docker.sh 
# Executing docker install script, commit: 442e66405c304fa92af8aadaa1d9b31bf4b0ad94
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
E: Essential packages were removed and -y was used without --allow-remove-essential.
```

then i install this package alone, ca-certificates, curl is ok, but apt-transport-https met question agina:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-apt-common python3-apt python3-debconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapt-pkg4.12
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-listchanges apt-utils tasksel tasksel-data
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https libapt-pkg4.12
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 847 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,112 kB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```